# MSVS 2015 with Xamarin Error on creating Blank App( Xamarin.Forms Portable)

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 successfully but on stage of creating a new Project when I choose "Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable)" I've got this error:

[image: Package Installation Error screenshot]

I updated Nuget Package Manager and Xamarin.Forms
and checked folder `Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable`
(I have v4.0,v4.5,v4.6,v5.0).

But nothing changed. That's my first experience with MSVS. How can I fix this problem?

System Setup:

- Windows 7 SP1
- Visual Studio 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
- .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure your Forms project is targeting .NET 4.5 or higher?

Right-click your Forms project in Solution explorer and choose Properties (near the bottom of context menu), then go to the Library tab.

[image]

Comment: Will you add your csproj file to your question?